# couchDb, deleting view index doesn't trigger reindex, still available

Tags: couchdb

It is my understanding that `couchDb` stores its view index in:

```
<dbName>/.<designDoc>/mrview/<hashOfDesignDoc>
```

After querying the view, this index is created. When I delete the index file, I am still able to access the view through `futon`, even after clearing my cache. I do not see the view index in `_active_tasks` and the `mrview` folder remains empty.

What is going on? I would expect `couchDb` to reindex the view.

Comment: Did you run a [view cleanup](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/compact.html#db-view-cleanup)?

Comment: No I didn't. I know that's the 'right' way to do it. I was mostly curious why manually deleting the index file wouldn't cause a similar effect.